# How to simulate the route style drew by Google Map service

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polyline

When we search route through Google Map web site, like this route:

http://goo.gl/maps/2mg8

Google Map will draw the route with nice style, something like as transparent light blue.

Now I want to simulate that style, something like,

```
new google.maps.Polyline({
   path: routePath,
   strokeColor: "#0000ff",
   strokeOpacity: 0.69,
   strokeWeight: 4
});
```

But I found it is quite difficult to simulate Google's own style. Anyone has similar experience and help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the code:

```
q.ra=function(a,b,c,d,e){
    this.color=b||"#0000ff";
    this.weight=Ug(c,5);
    this.opacity=Ug(d,0.45);
    ...
```

so reasonable options would appear to be

```
strokeColor: "#0000ff",
strokeOpacity: 0.45,
strokeWeight: 5
```

Comment: Awesome Andrew! That is exactly what I am looking for!